# angular reactive forms value does not get updated on using google address autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

This is my HTML

```
<input type="text" formControlName="Address" class="form-control col-md-12 addressfield" />
```

for google address I used

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementsByClassName("addressfield")[i], {types: ['geocode']});
        }
```

This worked fine and google address was showing options and I am able to select address.

But when I try to get the value, its only showing the text I typed

```
this.someForm.value.Address
```

For example, I typed the following and selected the first option

[image]

But when I tried to get the value, it was showing only the part that I typed and not the value that I selected

[image]

Comment: Why are you expecting anything other than the text you type when you try to access the `formControl` value? Getting the value of the input (i.e what you typed) is the expected result. `document.getElementsByClassName` returns the entire element. so just getting the `formControl` value is not equivalent to that.

Comment: thanks for asking, I have edited the question and added more details to it

Answer (score 1):

It won't work that way,

**Reason is :**
You are typing in your input formControl, but google address is being displayed on other elements created by google lib it self, so when you select one of the option it will set adreess to its crated element and not in your input. you need to set it up on it `place_changed` event.

Here is the code snippet, that might can help you:

```
let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementsByClassName("addressfield")[i], {types: ['geocode']});
autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
    let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    this.YOUR_FORM_GROUP.get('Address').setValue(place.formatted_address)
});
```

Comment: ah okay got it
so I have like 5 address fields, looks like I have to use IDs and add listeners for all of them separately

Comment: Yes , that will be the way

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to address the issue

In the .html file, I added an Id to the element

```
<input type="text"  formControlName="Address" #Address class="form-control col-md-12 addressfield" />
```

in the component.ts I added the below code

I added ElementRef to import

```
import { Component, NgModule,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```

I declared value

```
@ViewChild('Address',{static:false}) Address: ElementRef;
//here the 'Address' should be same as the ID value (#Address) that you used in the .html
```

then for fetching value from the input, instead of `this.someform.value.Address` I used

```
this.Address.nativeElement.value
```

This had the complete address populated by the google plugin